# Logging out (or in) of stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts

A bit of a dumb question, but...

I am on this unregistered account I created some time ago, but I now have a registered one I want to use instead... How do I log out of this one and into the new one?
Is there a good way of associating this one with the existing one?

Answer (score 2):

You log out with the "logout" button.

Re merging the two accounts; no problem - just let me/us know the other account, so I/we can confirm that it is yours. I checked by e-mail address and a few other things, but no obvious matches...

Answer (score 1):

When you are on as an unregistered account, **there is no `logout` button**.

But... if you follow the `register` link, you can select the Open-ID of your registered account and you will then be logged in as *that* user.

Then you can contact team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to merge the two account.

Comment: Wow, it has been a long time since I logged in anonymously, so I guess I missed this subtlety.

Comment: Me neither. This came up *very* recently over at StackExchange.

Comment: there is no logout button for unregistered users because it irrevocably destroys the browser cookie, the only thing that uniquely identifies them to us. You can go there manually, though : meta.stackoverflow.com/users/logout

Answer (score 0):

E-mail team@stackoverflow.com. They should be able to do the merge for you.

Comment: "meta" works just as well, probably quicker...

Comment: Sounds fair. :)